# SHDocVw InternetExplorer printing Serverside failing -- COM exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, printing, shdocvw

Am trying to print a file from server side via a WCF service deployed on IIS machine.
The following code gets worked on Win 2oo3 machine perfectly. But the same code is throwing a COM exception. Any idea about this. I guess its related to some permissions.
Here is the code

```
public void Print(string htmlFilename, string printer, short copies)
        {
            string currDefault = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                currDefault = GetDefaultPrinter();
                myPrinters.SetDefaultPrinter(printer);
                for (int i = 0; i < copies; i++)
                {
                    documentLoaded = false;
                    documentPrinted = false;

InternetExplorer  ie = new InternetExplorer  ();
                    ie.DocumentComplete += new SHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler(ie_DocumentComplete);
                    ie.PrintTemplateTeardown += new SHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_PrintTemplateTeardownEventHandler(ie_PrintTemplateTeardown);
                    object missing = Missing.Value;

                    ie.Navigate(htmlFilename, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
                    while (!documentLoaded && ie.QueryStatusWB(SHDocVw.OLECMDID.OLECMDID_PRINT) != SHDocVw.OLECMDF.OLECMDF_ENABLED)
                        Thread.Sleep(100);


                    ie.ExecWB(SHDocVw.OLECMDID.OLECMDID_PRINTPREVIEW, SHDocVw.OLECMDEXECOPT.OLECMDEXECOPT_DODEFAULT, ref missing, ref missing);

                    ie.ExecWB(SHDocVw.OLECMDID.OLECMDID_PRINT, SHDocVw.OLECMDEXECOPT.OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, ref missing, ref missing);
                    while (!documentPrinted)
                        Thread.Sleep(100);

                    ie.DocumentComplete -= ie_DocumentComplete;
                    ie.PrintTemplateTeardown -= ie_PrintTemplateTeardown;
                    ie.Quit();
                }
            }
            catch { throw; }
            finally
            {
                myPrinters.SetDefaultPrinter(currDefault);
            }
        }
```

And the Com Exception is as below exactly while creating an object for internetexplorer.

> [ERRORLOG] Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
>   error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)). :    at
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean
>   publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)    at
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)    at
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly,
>   Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean
>   fillCache)    at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean
>   nonPublic)    at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) 
>   [/ERRORLOG]

Moreover if i try to create an object as InternetExplorerMedium. then its working in 2008 but not in Win server 2003. I was very much clue less... Any help regarding will help a lot.

Regards,
Pavan N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i changed my own logic itself. I observed lot of difference w.r.t IE. especially IE9. all the DCOM seetings will be different. so with the name InternetExplorer ie = new InternetExplorer (); you cant create any object. its not either related to permission or OS. its related to IE version. Above code works only upto IE8.

Answer (score 1):

Check what versions of IE are installed on your 2003 server and your 2008 server.
Also, check for other IE-version-related SDK runtimes, etc. may need to be installed that aren't on the 2008 box as a result of different IE installs for different IE versions.  For example, I have an older client app where I have to install the DHTMLEdit ActiveX toolkit, which requires a separate step and you have to hunt down the setup routines on MSDN.
Also check the accounts and permissions between the 2003 and 2008 servers (the accounts used to run the WCF service) and see what's different.  A lot of security settings have probably been tightened up in 2008.