# SHDocVw - Creating IE9 com instances for printing

Tags: html, printing, com, internet-explorer-9, ole

I have .net 3.5 app which creates IE9 com object instances.

```
InternetExplorerClass  ie = new InternetExplorerClass();
```

Unfortunately for me, sometimes the creation of a new object fails with a generic 80004005 error.
[I've noticed a similar post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423108/shdocvw-internetexplorer-printing-serverside-failing-com-exception/13800650#13800650), which however did not put the solution for the IE9 case.

Can you help me with this one? how should i create the ie9 object so that i will not get any more errors?
Thank you, 
valentin